# Compare containers with GoogleTest

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to get a working googletest test that compares two vectors. For this I'm using google mock with its [matchers](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#matchers-matcherlist) but I get a C3861 error saying "ContainerEq identifier not found" and also C2512 saying "testing::AssertionResult has not a proper default constructor available". Why?

```
TEST(MyTestSuite, MyTest)
{
    std::vector<int> test1;
    std::vector<int> test2;

    ...

    EXPECT_THAT(test1, ContainerEq(test2));
}
```

Comment: This question has a recent correct answer by @phetdam #phetdam

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You're just missing gtest's `testing` namespace qualifier:

```
EXPECT_THAT(test1, ::testing::ContainerEq(test2));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `std::vector` does define `operator==`, why not just use `EXPECT_EQ`? Ex.

```cpp
#include <vector>

#include <gtest/gtest.h>

namespace {

TEST(MyTestSuite, MyTest)
{
  std::vector<double> a = {1, 2};
  std::vector<double> b = {1, 2};
  EXPECT_EQ(a, b);
}

}  // namespace
```

This works just fine. Although I mostly use C++17, `std::vector` definitely predates C++11.

For any of your own custom [*Container*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Container) types, define your own `operator==`.